# Django field.label_tag and field.errors not appearing on page

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django form that I am trying to display through a template, but for some strange reason, the field attributes aren't all appearing when I try to customize the template - specifically only the `label_tag` and `errors`.

When I display the form with the default, they appear:

```
{{ form.as_ul }}
```

But when I try to customize it, these fields won't render:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <li>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br/>
        {{ field.help_text }}
        {{ field }}
        {{ field.errors }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried displaying each of the [attributes listed in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields), and it is only a problem for `field.errors` and `field.label_tag`. Even just using the straight `field.label` works. Also, in forms on other pages, these fields do display properly using this method.

What could be the cause of this? I can add any other code that might be relevant, but I'm not sure what might be useful and I didn't want to vomit everything out here unnecessarily.

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered at least part of the problem:

The errors I was raising were in the model validation, not the form validation. I'm still not sure why the errors appeared with `{{ form.as_ul}}` but not otherwise, but I was able to fix my own problem by moving the validation (`clean` method) to the form.

As for the label_tag, I still have no idea what the issue was but it started spontaneously working again.

**Edit:** I just figured out the reason. The model validation is not associated with a specific field, so the `ValidationError` is not associated with a field and therefore doesn't appear in `{{ field.errors }}`. Instead, it is associated with the form in `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. Adding this tag in with the form made the proper error appear.